# I copied the URL text and paste in a browser new window using protractor but it is loading showing object object instead of actual URL

Tags: javascript, protractor

my actual URL is https://wallboard.ef.com/dashboard/1

```
 //open in a new tab
 var text=browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'v');
 browser.executeScript("window.open('"+text+"')");
```

resulted URL past in browser is https://wallboard.ef.com/[object%20Object]
how to get the actual URL mention above in a browser new tab

Comment: It means that `text` was a complex object, and not a mere string value as you expected. So go inspect it and see what properties it contains, and then pick the one holding the value you actually need.

Comment: yes this is showing object Object

Comment: You don’t need to repeat info that was already given.

Comment: how to handle this ?

Comment: You shoud see here sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'v') what is happening with protractor.Key.CONTROL and take a log.

Comment: @04FS said is right. you should debbuge step by step So go inspect it and see what properties it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the code now I used read from the clipboard.

browser.executeScript("navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => {window.open(text)});");